# Searching through an array of lists and checking if one of the values don't exist

Tags: python

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract all of the tags where a tag is = to mailto. I am running this on my own website. Only problem I have is lets say I've mentioned my email twice. I only want it to store it into the array once. With the store, I am also storing the path of url. Keeping it simple for now and making it just a "/".

I need a way to go through each element, find the 'url' and check for the value. If it does not exist, add it to the array.

Heres what I've gotten but it isn't correct.

```
def remove_duplicates(arr):

    final_list = []

    for page, data in enumerate(arr):
        if not final_list:
            final_list.append({'page': '/', 'url': data["url"]})
        print(final_list)


pageData = urllib.request.urlopen('<anysite>').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageData, 'html.parser')
initialData = []
data = []
for i in soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "mailto" in href):
    initialData.append({'page': '/', 'url': i.text})


remove_duplicates(initialData)
```

Comment: have you tried to use `in` keyword. Might go something like , `if x not in list:`

Answer (score 0):

**If  Only problem I have is lets say I've mentioned my email twice. I only want it to store it into the array once.**
Then I would advice you to make list to set and then making it back to list. By doing this you can eliminate the repeated data.

```
k = ['hello','world','hello']
set(k)
{'hello', 'world'}
list(set(k))
['hello', 'world']
```

And to check if a value exists in a list or not you can use the `not in` keyword.

Sample:

```
ls = [{'google': 'www.google.com'},{'facebuk': 'www.facebuk.com'},{ 'sample': 'www.sample.com'}, { 'sample': 'www.sample.com'}]
```

Now you can do this remove duplicates.

```
>>> [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in ls}]
[{'google': 'www.google.com'}, {'sample': 'www.sample.com'}, {'facebuk': 'www.facebuk.com'}]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I have keys (page & url)

Comment: @Pegasus Updated